# I there any way to have a scrollable composable inside a nestedscrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a scrollable composable and existing views. I need to have both inside a nestedscrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedScrollConnection. Here is an example:

```kotlin
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
            return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
        }

        override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
            return super.onPreFling(available)
        }

        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}

ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
) {

}
```

Comment: I don't believe this works with a xml view as parent in my case, a nestedscrollview